# Write without quotes in empty columns in a CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need to modify some columns of a CSV file to add some text in them. Once I've modified that columns I write the whole row, with the modified column to a new CSV file, but it does not keep the original format, as it adds "" in the empty columns.

The original CSV is a special dialect that I've registered as:

```
csv.register_dialect('puntocoma', delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

And it is part of my code:

```
with open(fileName,'rt', newline='', encoding='ISO8859-1') as fdata, \
     open(r'SampleFiles\Servergiro\fout.csv',
          'wt', newline='', encoding='ISO8859-1') as fout:
      reader=csv.DictReader(fdata, dialect='puntocoma')
      writer=csv.writer(fout, dialect='puntocoma')
```

I am reading the CSV with DictReader and with the CSV module
Then I modify the column that I need:

```
 for row in reader:
    for (key, value) in row.items():
        if key=='C' or key == 'D' or key == 'E':
            if row[key] != "":
                row[key] = '<something>' + value + '</something>'
```

And I write the modified content as it follows

```
content = list(row[i] for i in fields)
writer.writerow(content)
```

The original CSV has content like (header included):

```
"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J";"K";"L";"Ma";"No";"O 3";"O 4";"O 5"
"3123131";"Lorem";;;;;;;;;;;"Ipsum";"Ar";"Maquina Lorem";;;
"3003321";"HD 2.5' EP";;"as&auml;t 600 MB<br />Ere qweqsI (SAS)<br />tre qwe 15000 RPM<br />sasd ty 2.5 Zor<br />Are&auml;mis tyn<br />Ser Ja<br />&Uuml;tr ewas/s";;;;;;;;;"rew";"Asert ";"Trebol";"Casa";;
"3026273";"Sertro 5 M";;;;;;;;;;;"Rese";"Asert ";"Trebol";"Casa";;
```

But my modified CSV writes the following:

```
"3123131";"<something>Lorem</something>";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"<something>Ipsum</something>";"<something>Ar</something>";"<something>Maquina Lorem</something>";"";"";""
```

I've modified the original question adding the headers of the CSV. (The names of the headers are not the original.

How can I write the new CSV without quotes. My guess is about the dialect, but in reality it is a quote-all dialect except for columns that are empty.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also show what the first line—aka the header row—of the original CSV contains. I need this to reproduce the issue so I can test a possible solution. A couple more rows of data would be nice, too.

Comment: They python devs are discussing adding a `QUOTE_STRINGS` and `QUOTE_NOTNULL` to the csv module. It's still an open issue here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/67230

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you either have quotes everywhere (`QUOTE_ALL`) or no quotes (`QUOTE_MINIMAL`) (and other exotic options useless here).

I first posted a solution which wrote in a file buffer, then replaced the double quotes by nothing, but it was really a hack and could not manage strings containing quotes properly.

A better solution is to manually manage the quoting to force it if string is not empty, and don't put any if empty:

```
with open("input.csv") as fr, open("output.csv","w") as fw:
   csv.register_dialect('puntocoma', delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
   cr = csv.reader(fr,dialect="puntocoma")
   cw = csv.writer(fw,delimiter=';',quotechar='',escapechar="\\",quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
   cw.writerows(['"{}"'.format(x.replace('"','""')) if x else "" for x in row] for row in cr)
```

Here we tell `csv` no write no quotes at all (and we even pass an empty quote char). The manual quoting consists in generating the rows using a list comprehension quoting only if string is not empty, and doubling the quotes from within the string.

Comment: I've edited the question and I've added the header and 2 rows more. This solution looked good, however I believe because I have some HTML content on it, when I use QUOTE_NONE it returns a csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set.

Comment: Yes, you have to set `quotechar='',` (empty) too.

Comment: I have set it as it follows:
writer=csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';',  quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
And I get the csv.error

Comment: your original question didn't mention HTML data. I'll dig that further.

Comment: Yeah, it was my mistake. I focused on the empty columns and I did not give importance to the content of the columns.

Comment: don't worry, sometimes you want to create a [mcve] and it goes too far :). It may be useful for others as is... In the meantime, maybe my previous hack solution (that I edited out) could be of use.

Comment: @TMikonos you could try adding `escapechar='\\\` to your csv writer params